# jquery back to element before find or filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, find

I am looking a way to back to previous element which i was selected , take a look to this example :

```
$("Selector")
       .find(".class")
       .attr("data-foo" , "bar")
       .eq(1)
       .attr("data-isFirst" , "Yeah")
       .find("span")
       .filter(".blue")
       .addClass("IAmHere")
```

now if I want to back before filtering `.blue` or finding `.class` I can not do , I use caching selector like this :

```
var $main = $("Selector");
var $myDest = $main.find(".class");

$myDest.filter(".blue").addClass("IAmHere");
$myDest.filter(".red").addClass("ItIsRed");


var $myDestTwo = $main.find(".otherClass").eq(5);
$myDestTwo.filter(".foo").addClass("bar");
$myDestTwo.filter(".bar").addClass("foo");
```

but this is a lot of codes , if we can create some thing like `unFilter` or `unFind` with `jquery` fn it will be a cool thing like this :

```
$("Selector")
       .find(".class")
       .attr("data-foo" , "bar")
       .filter(".blue")
       .addClass("IAmHere")

       .unfilter(".blue")
       .addClass("ItIsRed")

       .unfind(".class")
       .find(".otherClass")
       .attr("data-foo" , "bar")
       .filter(".foo")
       .addClass("bar")

       .unfilter(".bar")
       .addClass("foo")
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear exactly what result you're trying to achieve here. It may be better if you could give details of the output you want instead of asking about an attempted flawed solution.

Comment: does `.closest('selector')` not work?

Comment: Why do `eq(1)` which only select a single element in the resultset and then`filter('.blue')` ? `filter` only reduces the current matched set not any children so seeing there is only a single element returned from `eq(1)` is `filter` not redundant? You can do `.find(".class.blue")` and `.find(".class.red")`instead to the same effect?

Comment: @fran you are right , but if we want do some thing with `.find(".class")`  like adding `attribute` or doing some thing else , and then `.filter("input")` and do some thing else with filtered element we need this.

Comment: @JoeshRazor If you use `eq()` you might as well just skip the filter and add it to the main selector. Unless you don't actually use `eq()` and only use filter then it makes sense.

Comment: @Fran yeah , you are right , i edited my question to have a better explanation , however I thought `.end()` is the best way to do the trick.thanks

Comment: @JoeshRazor `end()` is perfect - I upvoted that answer myself too. The only reason I added the alternative was if you needed to go further up the chain than what `end()` leads you too, which based on the original post wasn't too clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [end](https://api.jquery.com/end/) function

```
$("Selector").find(".red").addClass("IAmRed").end().find('.blue').addClass("IAmRBlue").end();
```

Comment: Good point , this solve otur problem with find , does end works for back to element before `.filter("foo")` ? or just back to element before `.find("foo")`

Comment: it goes back to the `$("Selector")`

Comment: if you want to add the class to `.otherClass.foo` you just continue chaining `.find(".otherClass.foo").addClass("bar").end().find(".otherClass.bar").addClass("foo").end();`

Answer (score 1):

Your `eq()` is confusing as you call `filter` on a set of 1, meaning the filter is redundant and you might as well make anything you filter on part of the original selector.

Anyway, You can use closest as an alternative if you need to go further up the chain than what `end()` gets you too *(Though `end()` should work fine)*:

```
$(main).find(myClass).filter('.blue').addClass('itIsBlue').closest(main).find(myClass).filter('.red').addClass('itIsRed')
```

You didn't post any HTML so trying to understand exactly what your desired end result would be is challenging. Hence  made up some HTML simply to demonstrate the use of `closest`. You need to change any logic to apply to your HTML off course as needed.

```js
function traversalCode() {
  var main = '.mySelector';
  var myClass = '.myClass';
  var otherClass = '.otherClass';

  $(main)
    .find(myClass).filter('.blue').addClass('itIsBlue')
    .closest(main)
    .find(myClass).filter('.red').addClass('itIsRed')
    .closest(main)
    .find(otherClass).filter('.yellow').addClass('itIsYellow')
    .closest(main)
    .find(otherClass).filter('.green').addClass('itIsGreen')
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  traversalCode();
})
```

```css
.itIsBlue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.itIsRed {
  background-color: pink;
}

.itIsYellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.itIsGreen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mySelector">
  <div class="myClass red">
    <span>myClass red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="otherClass yellow">
    <span>otherClass yellow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myClass red">
    <span>myClass red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="otherClass green">
    <span>otherClass green</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myClass blue">
    <span>myClass blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="otherClass yellow">
    <span>otherClass yellow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myClass blue">
    <span>myClass blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="otherClass green">
    <span>otherClass green</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myClass blue">
    <span>myClass blue</span>
  </div>
  <div class="otherClass green">
    <span>otherClass green</span>
  </div>
  <div class="myClass red">
    <span>myClass red</span>
  </div>
  <div class="otherClass yellow">
    <span>otherClass yellow</span>
  </div>
</div>
```